# How am I able to use R or Python to extract the netCDF/nc data that I need?

Tags: python, r, netcdf

I am looking to extract some data from EarthData (NASA) and I have already obtained the links in the netCDF format.

A sample of the links are as such:
[https://goldsmr5.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2I6NPANA.5.12.4/2012/01/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np.20120101.nc4.nc4?PS[0:3][156:301][389:555],V[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],T[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],SLP[0:3][156:301][389:555],U[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],QV[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],H[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],O3[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],time,lat[156:301],lon[389:555],lev](https://goldsmr5.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2I6NPANA.5.12.4/2012/01/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np.20120101.nc4.nc4?PS%5B0:3%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,V%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,T%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,SLP%5B0:3%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,U%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,QV%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,H%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,O3%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,time,lat%5B156:301%5D,lon%5B389:555%5D,lev)
[https://goldsmr5.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2I6NPANA.5.12.4/2012/01/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np.20120102.nc4.nc4?PS[0:3][156:301][389:555],V[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],T[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],SLP[0:3][156:301][389:555],U[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],QV[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],H[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],O3[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],time,lat[156:301],lon[389:555],lev](https://goldsmr5.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2I6NPANA.5.12.4/2012/01/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np.20120102.nc4.nc4?PS%5B0:3%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,V%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,T%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,SLP%5B0:3%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,U%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,QV%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,H%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,O3%5B0:3%5D%5B0:41%5D%5B156:301%5D%5B389:555%5D,time,lat%5B156:301%5D,lon%5B389:555%5D,lev)

Basically out of all of my links, the only thing that changes is the date (from 20120101 to 20120102 and so on). I would like to use the loop function to go through all my lists of urls to extract the data into nc4 format, using a R or Python code?

To extract a single data, I have tried:

```
destfile<-"C:/Users/Desktop/output"
url <- "https://username:password@goldsmr5.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2I6NPANA.5.12.4/2012/01/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np.20120102.nc4.nc4?PS[0:3][156:301][389:555],V[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],T[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],SLP[0:3][156:301][389:555],U[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],QV[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],H[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],O3[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],time,lat[156:301],lon[389:555],lev"
download.file(url, destfile)
```

Comment: The pages at the links you provide are password protected. Could you provide a snippet of the data with your question? Have you looked at the relevant libraries (looks like these are `ncdf4 ` in R, `pyNIO` and `netCDF4-python` in python)?

Answer (score 1):

The below might work out, changing start and end date. Obviously it is untested as your example is not reproducible. Files are output into files names 'yyyymmdd' in the output folder.

```
startdate <- as.Date('2012-01-01')
enddate <- as.Date('2012-01-02')
dest <- "C:/Users/Desktop/output"
dates <- seq(startdate, enddate)
download_nasa_file <- function(date){
  url <- paste0("https://username:password@goldsmr5.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2I6NPANA.5.12.4/2012/01/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np."
       , format(date, '%Y%m%d'), 
         ".nc4.nc4?PS[0:3][156:301][389:555],V[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],T[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],SLP[0:3][156:301][389:555],U[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],QV[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],H[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],O3[0:3][0:41][156:301][389:555],time,lat[156:301],lon[389:555],lev")
  res <- try(download.file(url, file.path(dest, format(date, '%Y%m%d'))))
  if(inherits(res, 'try-error'))
    return NULL
  res 
)))
}
results <- lapply(dates, download_nasa_file)
```